# How many binary trees are there, if the leafs's order from left to right is fixed?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, catalan

Let's represent the tree via list.

If the number of the leafs is two, A and B. Then there is only one tree (A B).

If the number of the leafs is three, A, B and C. Then there are two trees ((A B) C) and (A (B C)).

So if there are N leafs, how many trees are there?

Comment: ***"Let's represent the tree via list."*** Clarify please how you do that?

Comment: Here is a hint: if the number of leaves is a power of 2, then there is one binary tree with the leaves in the specified order.

Comment: @gogognome I don't think that's true. For example, check this:http://draw.to/DfUt2p. It shows an 8-leaf binary tree which isn't balanced.

Comment: @louxiu is there any restriction on the degree of internal nodes? For example, if you allow degree = 1 then there is an infinite number of binary trees with N nodes in the given order. Also, is there any restriction on total number of nodes?

Comment: Indeed @OmriBarel, you are right. I assumed the binary tree was balanced and the and that the non-leaf-nodes have two child nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let the number of binary trees with `N` leaves be `T(N)`.

We have `T(1) = T(2) = 1`, as can be immediately seen, and for `N > 2` we can split at the root, obtaining two subtrees with fewer leaves. Or, equivalently, we can assemble a binary tree with `N` leaves from two non-empty binary trees with `k` and `N-k` leaves respectively. The condition that both subtrees are non-empty translates to `1 <= k <= N-1`. So we have the recursion

```
      N-1
T(N) = ∑  T(k) * T(N-k)
      k=1
```

If the recursion is not yet known, it is not difficult to compute the first few values

```
1,1,2,5,14,42,132,429,1430,4862,16796
```

and google them. One finds that these are the [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number),

```
C(n) = (2*n)! / (n! * (n+1)!)
```

offset by one, so

```
T(N) = C(N-1)
```

which can be computed much faster than the recursion.

Comment: +1, nice explanation. And I like catalan numbers! So many things are reduced into them

Comment: Note that there is a condition here on the degree of internal nodes. If for some subtree the root is of degree 1 then you can't split the subtree into two non-empty sub-subtrees.

Comment: @OmriBarel Of course every non-leaf must have two children, otherwise you'd have ℵ_0 trees for all `N > 0`.